# How would passing function as props to React component cause performance implications?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just read [Ract doc on Passing Functions to Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html), it seems using bind and arrow function would both break React's performance optimization.

For example,

```
class Foo extends React.PureComponent {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}


class Foo extends React.PureComponent {
  handleClick() {
    console.log('Click happened');
  }
  render() {
    return <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Click Me</button>;
  }
}
```

What I know is both of them are creating new callback function when render method is called.

1. For the child component Button, would it cause extra rendering as I
   suppose React.PureComponent and React.memo are using reference check
   to see if props are changed?
2. If so, would the extra rendering happen on both React's virtual DOM
       and the actual DOM?

Based on my experiments (basically using setInterval to recreate the callback function), it seems that the React virtual DOM has extra rendering since the render is called with extra times. However, the actual DOM seems not having extra rendering. Not sure if it is because the callback function is not part of the DOM.

3. I'm also wondering the common solution to prevent such performance issue. One possible solution I thought of is to cache the callback so we don't need to bind them again and agin. Is there any better solution?

Comment: In the case of the first example, I wouldn't say it will create 2 callbacks, it will create an object linked to the previous function object with this bound to the method. In the second case it will create a function that will call the other function. In other words, there's no cost except memory for the first 1 but the second case will actually call 2 methods. Using `bind` would be the fastest solution regardless of the rest.

Comment: Q1 - yes it would cause re-rendering since reference changes. Q2 - actual DOM won't re-render cos nothing's actually changed. Q3 - the doc you linked already has solutions, e.g. binding in the constructor or using class properties